# Provide HTML output for paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am having an issue when I pull data into the WordPress website.

I use the code snippet below to print the category description.

```
<p> {{ currentTax.activeTerm.description}} </p>
```

It works fine, it prints description but it is not HTML output. Links, bold or other tags I enter in category don't show in the output.

For example it prints like this

This is description of the car category. In order to check cars check this link `<a href="cars.php" > Cars</a>`

It doesn't display a link, it shows text. Is there any way to quickly solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with innerHTML property binding:

```
<p [innerHTML]="currentTax.activeTerm.description"></p>
```

See: [Sanitization and security contexts](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts)

Answer (score 0):

refer dangerouslysetinnerhtml or use iframe to load the content. But I prefer to use iframe